# Is there a way to color visited links with AngularJS and UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs

When you visit regular links you can set visited style with css. But when you use AngularJS with UI-Router you can't do this. Is there a way for me to color the visited links so that users can see what they have visited and not?

If this is possible, how should I do it?

Comment: Why you say "But when you use AngularJS with UI-Router you can't do this". CSS **a:visited** style still applies doesn't matter if it's a SPA or not

Comment: I am sorry, but it did not work for me, maybe I did something wrong..

Comment: Hmm, I could not reproduce it, http://plnkr.co/edit/FICmn3MBJgncsiIDtzRt?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this for `a:visited` to work

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Check the updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/jJ6i5765ir57YbcaF6pX?p=preview